# LaTeX letter with adress field in the right place for a "C5 envelope with window"

Tags: latex, styles

Does anybody know of a good way to write simple paper letters in LaTeX, so that the formatting shows the receivers address on the right place so I will show in the window of those C5 envelops with a "address window" (see picture)?

[image: envelope]

Those envelope follows some kind of standard here in Sweden, 
I would like too use them since my handwriting is not that good looking.

How can I get a box with the receivers address in the upper right corner on the first page?

---

**Update**:
I think the letter should conform to SS 34321 (Swedish Standard).

**Update**: 
A copy of this question can be found over at the tex.stackexchange site, 
where it has a working example:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/latex-letter-with-adress-field-in-the-right-place-for-a-c5-envelope-with-window

Comment: As you seem aware of based on your comment below, there exists http://tex.stackexchange.com/ perhaps this question should be moved there.

Comment: I am now :) But the question is already "manually" moved so no need to do much but add a link to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to find any packages which use the Swedish standards you cite. But I think if you look in the [wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Letters#Envelopes) that [Dave](https://superuser.com/users/10554/daveparillo) [mentioned](https://superuser.com/questions/58404/latex-letter-with-adress-field-in-the-right-place-for-a-c5-envelope-with-window/58613#58613) and follow the example previous to the Koma example which uses the standard letter package, you should be able to measure the window dimensions and use them with the `parindent` command.

Alternatively you could try modifying the [variables for Koma's window information](http://www.miwie.org/tex-refs/html/latex-packages.html#id2563693).
They seem to be: `toaddrvpos, toaddrhpos, toaddrwidth, toaddrindent`.

Comment: This I must try

Answer (score 1):

There's a wikibook with an [example](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Letters#Windowed_envelopes) - it discusses using the letter class (scrlttr2) from CTAN's [KOMA package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/).  I've never done what you're trying, but I expect this will work.

**Update**

I was not intending that the wikibook example would work 'out of the box' for you, but I knew it would be close.  Are you using A4 paper?  If not you need to adjust that using \LetterOptionNeedsPapersize.  Page 197 of the [english documentation for koma](http://ctan.unixbrain.com/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf) explains how to use `\backaddress` , `\backaddressseparator`, and `\backaddrheight` to adjust how your return address gets aligned in the address window.

If you can't get it right simply using these parameters, you may have to edit the lco file in the koma package by hand.

Comment: The first example was really close, but the address was approx 2-3cm to far down on the page (so it was right below the address window on the envelope)...

Comment: You mean CTAN, not CPAN.

Comment: @dlamblin - you are so right!  Thanks for noticing